# Failed to launch, Desktop file didn't specify Exec file

Tags: 18.04, .desktop

I recently installed UGet download manager.

When I try to open it, it is showing the error:

> Failed to launch "UGet"
>
> Desktop file didn't specify Exec field

How to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The .desktop file should look like this...

```
/usr/share/applications$ ls -al uget*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 296 Mar 16  2018 uget-gtk.desktop
```

/usr/share/applications$ more uget-gtk.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=uGet
GenericName=Download Manager
Comment=Download multiple URLs and apply it to one of setting/queue.
Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=x11 uget-gtk %u
Icon=uget-icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
Keywords=filetransfer;download files;download manager;
```